# Sitecore Install Assistance - Installation error SC-v9.3 - Unable to parse [resolvepath(variable('IdentityServer_Package

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-assistant

I'm trying to install the `Sitecore v9.3` with `Sitecore Install Assistance`, however, I did get this error.

**Note**: The `Sitecore.IdentityServer 4.0.0 rev. 00257 (OnPrem)_identityserver.scwdp.zip` file does exist.

**Log File:**

```
Unable to parse [resolvepath(variable('IdentityServer_Package'))] - 
Exception calling "InvokeWithContext" with "2" argument(s): "The running         
command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" 
or common parameter is set to Stop: Cannot find path 
'C:\Users\erjan\Desktop\Sitecore\Sitecore Installations\Sitecore 
9.3\Graphical setup package for XP Single\pacakges\Sitecore 9.3.0 rev. 
003498 (Setup XP0 Developer Workstation rev. 1.1.0- 
r105)\Sitecore.IdentityServer 4.0.0 rev. 00257 
(OnPrem)_identityserver.scwdp.zip' because it does not exist."
```

**SIA Error:**
[image: Sitecore Install Assistance - SC v9.3 installation error.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a solution to this issue. It looks like a similar issue happened when Sitecore v9.3 is installed by using the "Sitecore Installation Framework" PowerShell scripts. 
Instead of updating "install.ps1" you have to update "setup.exe.config" file.

**Solution:**

1. Open the file "setup.exe.config" file which is under the root folder of the installation package that you downloaded from Sitecore (Sitecore 9.3.0 rev. 003498 (Setup XP0 Developer Workstation rev. 1.1.0-r105))
2. Search for value=".\Sitecore.IdentityServer * rev. * (OnPrem)_identityserver.scwdp.zip"
3. Update the value with the actual file name like value=".\Sitecore.IdentityServer 4.0.0 rev. 00257 (OnPrem)_identityserver.scwdp.zip"
4. Save an restart the installation process.

**Note:** If this does not work. Rename the "Sitecore.IdentityServer 4.0.0 rev. 00257 (OnPrem)_identityserver.scwdp.zip" for something simple like "IdentityServer.scwdp.zip" update the "setup.exe.config". Restart the installation process. This will work.

I have recorded a Sitecore Tutorial and explained how to install Sitecore v9.3 and in this video, I also explained how I solved this issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFyLQEkz3U8&t=4s

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue.

It was because of my **FULLPATH** name length to '*Sitecore.IdentityServer 4.0.0 rev. 00257 (OnPrem)_identityserver.scwdp.zip*' was more than Windows **MAX_PATH** **limit** (260 characters).

In your case full path name length is 266 characters:

[image]

Just solved by moving to installation files to 'D:/s93install'.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if you forget to each of the scwdp files in the zip file to the root of your install folder when using SIF; e.g the zip files in: `XP0 Configuration files 9.3.0 rev. 003498.zip`